# HTMLEditorExtender not working fine in IE

Tags: asp.net, htmleditorextender

I have an issue by using the HTMLEditorExtender component.
I'm creating a web form on which I have a textbox, extended with this component. I noted that the HTMLEditorExtender creates a

tags to manage a new line or a new paragraph, by using Internet Explorer.

With Chrome or Firefox, there is not any

tags added, but only  tags.

and this issue is also present in the [Demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx) does anybody have a work around for this issue..??

And another issue is that the Cut Copy and Paste icons in the tool bar are not getting rendered in FireFox and Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that each browser will interpret rich text editors (contenteditable="true") of the  differently. So when you hit enter, it will either add paragraphs or divs. If you hold shift + enter, you get a br in IE but not in other browsers.

The only way I can see the output matching up is to format the data on postback by running some regular expressions or a replace to change the tags.